# Erlang variable pattern matching

Tags: sockets, erlang, pattern-matching, sockjs

I have a `service_echo` function in a simple chat application which uses SockJS for implementing multi-user private chat. I created an ETS table for the list of online users. By storing SockJS session, I thought to send message to that Connection whenever I receive a message from a different Connection.

Here is my `service_echo` code.

```
service_echo(Conn, {recv, Data}, state) ->
    Obj = mochijson2:decode(Data),
    {struct, JsonData} = Obj,
    Name = proplists:get_value(<<"name">>, JsonData),
    A = ets:lookup(username,Name),
    io:format("~p",[Conn]),
    if
      length(A) =:= 0 ->
          ets:insert(username,{Name,Conn});
      true ->
          [{AA,BB}] = ets:lookup(username,Name),

          BB:send(Data)
    end,

     io:format("hello");
```

Even though Conn and BB are same, still `Conn:send(data)` sends a valid data to the browser while `BB:send(Data)` does nothing and even does not show an error.
Since I'm a new to Erlang, please excuse me for any unintented mistakes.

Comment: Is this really the code you've been running, or did you type it in separately for StackOverflow? For example, you have "state" with lowercase in the first line, so this function will never work at all. To help people answer, make sure you show the exact code you're trying to run.

Comment: `StateEcho = sockjs_handler:init_state(
                  <<"/echo">>, fun service_echo/3, state,
                  [{response_limit, 4096}]),` calls the service_echo function.This is the code which I'm running but messages are not being sent by `BB:send(Data)`.

Comment: This piece of code, cannot compile, Var - on line 12 - is unbound. So as say richard, some information is miising. Anyway, to be able to help you, it could be interresting to know what you have stored in BB, because, it is the function send/1 in module BB which is responsible to send the message - line 13.

Comment: @Pascal I had done some editing before posting the question to make it simple. Thanks. BB is identical to Conn which is a SockJS connection through websockets.Output of io:format for Conn will look like `{<0.161.0>,
                       [{peername,{{127,0,0,1},56247}},
                        {sockname,{{127,0,0,1},56247}},
                        {path,"/echo/039/62l0slqe/websocket"},
                        {headers,[]}]}}`.What is annoying is Conn:send works where as BB which is the same as Conn through pattern matching doesn't work as the way Conn works. `BB:send()` not working.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me advise you on never using `length(A) =:= 0` for testing whether the list `A` is empty or not; if `A` a long list, counting its elements will cost you a lot, although the result will not actually be used.  Use `A =:= []` instead, simpler and better.

I don't understand why you're saying that `Conn` and `BB` are the same.  This does not follow from the code that you have posted here.  If `Name` is not in the table, you insert an entry `{Name, Conn}`.  Otherwise, if `Name` exists in the table and is related to a single object `BB`, you assume that this `BB` is a module and you call the `send` function defined therein.

It could be that you're reading wrong the semantics of `if` --- if that's the case, don't let the `true` guard confuse you, this is how an if-then-else is written in Erlang.  Maybe you wanted to have something like:

```
    ...
    A = ets:lookup(username,Name),
    if
      A =:= [] ->
        ets:insert(username,{Name,Conn})
    end,
    [{_,BB}] = ets:lookup(username,Name),
    BB:send(Data)
    ...
```

or even better:

```
    ...
    A = ets:lookup(T,Name),
    if
      A =:= [] ->
        ets:insert(T,{Name,Conn}),
        BB = Conn;
      true ->
        [{_,BB}] = A
    end,
    BB:send(Data)
    ...
```

On the other hand, it could be that I misunderstood what you're trying to do.  If that's the case, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for giving more insight.My approach definitely lacks efficiency. But the problem is the `BB` which is retrieved after `[{_,BB}]=A` appears the same as `Conn` which is a SockJS variable but   doesn't send Data `BB:send(data)` but `Conn:send(Data)` works. In the ETS lookup table the second element of the tuple is identical to a `Conn` instance. But when retrieved after pattern matching doesn't send `Data` as `Conn` does. I think I've confused everyone out here. My apologies.